# What's wrong in my code? Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to unfollow all people i follow.
What is wrong in my code?

```
import tweepy
#unfollow script

consumer_key =  ""

consumer_secret = ""

access_token = ""

access_token_secret = ""


#  llölölöälöä
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

def unfollow():
    print("[+] Unfollowing in progress...")
    for user in api.followers():
        api.destroyfriendship(user) 

test = input("Type ENTER if you want to start.")
test = True

if test is True:
    unfollow()

else:
    print("Thanks for using my script")
```

AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'destroyfriendship'

Comment: Try `destroy_friendship` instead. See [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.destroy_friendship)

Comment: Than i get error 414.

Comment: The method gets called properly so your question is solved. If you are facing another problem, open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the latest version of the Tweepy API, you have typo in your method call.

```
api.destroyfriendship(user)
```

The correct call should be as follows:

```
api.destroy_friendship(user)
```

Please see the [api-reference](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#api-reference)